# Gson NumberFormatException

Tags: java, gson, numberformatexception

If I try to deserialize my json:

```
String myjson = "

      {
       "intIdfCuenta":"4720",
       "intIdfSubcuenta":"0",
       "floatImporte":"5,2",
       "strSigno":"D",
       "strIdfClave":"FT",
       "strDocumento":"1",
       "strDocumentoReferencia":"",
       "strAmpliacion":"",
       "strIdfTipoExtension":"IS",
       "id":"3"
      }";


viewLineaAsiento asiento =  gson.fromJson(formpla.getViewlineaasiento(),viewLineaAsiento.class);
```

I get this error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5,2"

How can I parse "5,2" to Double???

I know that if I use `"floatImporte":"5.2"` I can parse it without any problem but I what to parse `"floatImporte":"5,2"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your JSON is in first place bad. You shouldn't be representing numbers as strings at all. You should basically either have all `String` properties in your `ViewLineaAsiento` Java bean object representation as well, or to remove those doublequotes from JSON properties which represent numbers (and fix the fraction separator to be `.` instead of `,`).

If you're absolutely posisive that you want to continue using this bad JSON and fix the problem by a workaround/hack instead of fixing the problem by its roots, then you'd need to create a [custom Gson deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer). Here's a kickoff example:

```
public static class BadDoubleDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Double> {

    @Override
    public Double deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(element.getAsString().replace(',', '.'));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

You can register it via `GsonBuilder#registerTypeAdapter()` as follows:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new BadDoubleDeserializer()).create();
ViewLineaAsiento asiento = gson.fromJson(myjson, ViewLineaAsiento.class);
```

Comment: Where exactly should I register it via GsonBuilder ? I only use gson in my imports in the class...

Comment: @BalusC what happens if we use declare `intIdfCuenta` as Number in Kotlin will the serialization/Deserialization work out of the box ?